# Chrome Extension: using document.querySelector in background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to set a variable equal to the favicon url of the current page. Are you not able to do this in the background script? How else could I get the current page's favicon url that the user is on?

## background.js

```
var currentFaviconURL = document.querySelector("link[rel*='shortcut icon']").href;
console.log(currentFaviconURL);
```

## console

```
Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading and manipulating DOM, you must use Content Scripts.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: How should I set a variable in the background script if I need to find the current page's favicon then?

Comment: You can edit and read only extension body with background script. If you want to edit or read html document of current page, you can set that in content script.

Comment: @RedLemon I am fetching HTML of a page in `background.js`. I want to use jQuery, may I pass the HTML from background to `contentscript` and use jQuery, all without any visibity?